# How to save Pandas DataFrame in parquet format in AWS lambda keeping in mind deployment package or aws lambda layer size

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, parquet

I am trying to save Pandas DataFrame in parquet format in AWS lambda keeping in mind deployment package or aws lambda layer size.

The maximum package size limit of AWS lambda is 250 MB. When I pip install pyarrow, the deployment package size becomes around 350 MB.

Comment: What's the issue? The package is too big?

Comment: The maximum package size limit of AWS lambda is 250 MB. When I pip install pyarrow, the deployment package size becomes around 350 MB.